# HTML/CSS Hover with multiple links

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to have an image on a webpage, that when hovered, turns into two different linked images?   I'd like to have the main image there, but when you mouse over the "Phones" picture, you can choose which product (Apple or Android) that you're interested in. And then you can either click on Apple and be redirected to [Site A] or click Android and be directed to [Site B].

[image]

Comment: You can attach mouseover functionality to the image and show other images.

Comment: if you want to use just 1 element, it should not be an empty element (like an `img`), then we can add 2 pseudo-elements to render the 2 links ***but*** we need to handle the click event correctly based on the coordinates of the clicked point to determine which ***virtual*** link is clicked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a CSS-only solution: http://jsfiddle.net/QArRL/.

HTML:

```
<div id = "image"><a href = "#">apple</a><a href = "#">android</a></div>
```

CSS:

```
#image {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: url(http://placehold.it/200x100) no-repeat;
}

#image > a {
    display: none;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    font: bold 12px/100px Sans-Serif;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background-color: rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.9);
}

#image:hover > a {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I used this method and it's working just how I want it!

Comment: Great!  Feel free to mark the question as solved at your convenience.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking to create a menu. Create a div with 2 links and the css display: none attribute set. Set the hover event handler (via jquery for example) for your main link (Phones) to toggle the visibility of the div.

```
#menu { display: none }

 $("#phones").hover(
  function() {
    $("#menu").show();
  }, function() {
    $("#menu").hide();
  });
```

Comment: ***have an image on a webpage, that when hovered, turns into two different linked images*** looks like the OP meant to use only 1 image, it's strange but it's his want.

Comment: it doesn't matter, we're using divs here

Comment: @andypopa the point here is looks like he wants to use ***only 1*** element, you used 2 elements, that's why I mentioned about pseudo-elements in my comment under the OP's question, and also that's why he should use an element not of an empty element (like an image) so that we can create pseudo-elements, of course the image can be renderd by using background-image instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can do whatever you want on '**Onmouseover**' event, just register the image with **'onmouseover'** with a function and then dynamically create two image elements over there using **createElement('img')** and then give them source using **'imageNode.src'**. Thats it. Done.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need:

HTML

```
<div class="menu">
    <img src="" alt="phones">
    <a href=""><img src="" alt="android"></a>
    <a href=""><img src="" alt="apple"></a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.menu{

width:200px;
height:100px;

}

.menu a{

display:none;
width:100px;
height:100px;
float:left;

}


.menu > img{

display:block;
width:200px;
height:100px;

}

.menu:hover > img{

display:none;

}


.menu:hover a{

display:block;

}
```